# How to display results from a JavaScript function to an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to display values from a JavaScript to a table in HTML. I am trying to display just the even numbers between a starting number and a ending number. I believe my functions are correct but for some reason the values do not display on the page when submitted. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

```js
function clearErrors() {
  for (var loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < document.forms["displayEvens"].elements.length; loopCounter++) {
    if (document.forms["displayEvens"].elements[loopCounter]
      .parentElement.className.indexOf("has-") != -1) {

      document.forms["displayEvens"].elements[loopCounter]
        .parentElement.className = "form-group";
    }
  }
}

function resetForm() {
  clearErrors();
  document.forms["displayEvens"]["startingNumber"].value = "";
  document.forms["displayEvens"]["endingNumber"].value = "";
  document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].value = "";
  document.getElementById("results").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("submitButton").innerText = "DisplayEvens";
  document.forms["displayEvens"]["startingNumber"].focus();
}

function displayEvens(startingNumber, endingNumber, step) {

  var startingNumber =
    parseInt(document.getElementById("startingNum").value);
  var endingNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("endingNum").value);
  var step = parseInt(document.getElementById("stepNum").value);
  var evenNums = [];
  for (var i = startingNumber; i < endingNumber; i += step) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      evenNums.push(i);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("evens").innerText = evenNums;
}

function validateItems() {
  clearErrors();
  displayEvens(startingNumber, endingNumber, step);

  console.trace("got here!");

  //var startingNumber = document.forms["displayEvens"]
  ["startingNumber"].value;
  //var endingNumber = document.forms["displayEvens"]
  ["endingNumber"].value;
  //var step = document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].value;
  if (startingNumber == "" || isNaN(startingNumber)) {
    alert("Starting Number must be filled in with a number.");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["startingNumber"]
      .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error";
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["startingNumber"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (endingNumber == "" || isNaN(endingNumber)) {
    alert("Ending Number must be filled in with a number.");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["endingNumber"]
      .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["endingNumber"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (endingNumber <= startingNumber) {
    alert("Ending Number must be greater than the Starting number.");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["endingNumber"]
      .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["endingNumber"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (step == "" || isNaN(step)) {
    alert("Step Number must be filled in with a number.");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"]
      .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (step < 0) {
    alert("Step Number must be filled in with a positive number.");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"]
      .parentElement.className = "form-group has-error"
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].focus();
    return false;
  }

  //document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
  //document.getElementById("submitButton").innerText = "Recalculate";
  document.getElementById("startingNum").innerText =
    Number(startingNumber);
  document.getElementById("endingNum").innerText = Number(endingNumber);
  document.getElementById("stepNum").innerText = Number(step);
  document.getElementById("evens").innerText = Number(evenNums);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="displayEvens.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Display Evens</h1>
    <form name="displayEvens" onsubmit="return validateItems();" onreset="resetForm();">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="startingNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-
    label">Starting Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" ` id="startingNumber" ` placeholder="Enter a number" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="endingNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-` 
    label">Ending` 
    Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="endingNumber" placeholder="Enter a number" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="step" class="col-sm-2 col-form-
    label">Step</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="step" placeholder="Enter a number" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-
    default">Display Evens</button>
      <button type="reset" id="resetButton" class="btn">Reset</button>
    </form>
    </br>
    <table id="results" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Even numbers between <span id="startingNum"></span> and
            <span id="endingNum"></span> by <span id="stepNum"></span></td>
          <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span id="evens"></span></td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--<div id="results" style="display:none;">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <span id="evens"></span>
        <h3>Your Starting Number:</h3>
        <span id="start"></span></br>
        <h3>Your Ending Number:</h3>
        <span id="end"></span></br>
        <h3>Your Step Number:</h3>
        <span id="step"></span>
    </div>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental issue wrong with your html. You are using the same id attribute on multiple elements. The id attribute should be used only on one element because it is a unique identifier.

Also when you have cleaned that up you can change your line

`document.getElementById("endingNum").innerText = Number(endingNumber);`

replace it with

`document.getElementById("endingNum").append(Number(endingNumber))`

instead

Comment: Thank you for your help. If it’s not too much trouble would you point out to me where I was using the same id for multiple elements? Were you talking about the span id?

Comment: Yeah the span `id` attributes was used again in some of your `input` elements

Comment: Won't mind if you help with an upvote for the answer if it helped you :-)